# ogr ExportToWkt support for m value?

Tags: python, shapefile, ogr, well-known-text

I'm trying to parse a shapefile with ogr and export the values to WKT. The geometries contain a m value but this is not showing in the WKT output.

Does ogr support 4D/m values?

```
# My code
from osgeo import ogr
shp = ogr.Open(shapefile.shp)
lyr = shp.GetLayer()
for feature in lyr:
   # output - 'LINESTRING (557729 4970394 1869,557024 4970372 1806, ...)'
   # It should be - 'LINESTRING (557729 4970394 1869 1,557024 4970372 1806 2, ...)'
   print(feature.GetGeometryRef().ExportToWkt())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the 2.1 version, ogr support 4D/m values

```
wkt = "POINT (557729 4970394 1869 1)"
point = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(wkt)
point.GetPointZM()
(557729.0, 4970394.0, 1869.0, 1.0)
point.GetX()
557729.0
point.GetY()
4970394.0
point.GetZ()
1869.0
point.GetM()
1.0
```

But

```
point.ExportToWkt()
'POINT (557729 4970394 1869)'
# and GeoJson
point.ExportToJSON()
'{ "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 557729.0, 4970394.0, 1869.0 ] }'
```

Comment: Upgrading to v2.x and realizing that support for M is still limited (not available in ExportToWkt etc) helped. I was able to extract the M value by breaking the line into points and using GetM(). Thanks!